# How do I read data from a existing database in the assets folder on Flutter web. db or sqlite

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

How do I read data from a existing database in the assets folder on Flutter web. or read database from url like: https://example.com/mydatabase.db or .sqlite

Comment: Hi could you please explain more elaborately?

Comment: I need read database from assets folder on my project by Flutter web not Android or read database by url come from server like this:  https://example.com/mydatabase.db

Comment: to read or run a db on web you would need an engine to run queries on which to my knowledge wouldn't be possible on web without an external source. You can use free tools like firebase, mongo etc to create and execute your commands. Else another workaround I could think of is using an CSV file as a database and reading that.

If you think this would be helpful I can create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`sqflite`](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) package as said [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite).

Comment: Unfortunately, sqflite not support Flutter web